# Python: Naming types and assigning variables outside a function from within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'd like to be able to easily create new types, plus (optionally) add some information about them (say some docs, and a set of variable names they often come under).

The straightforward way to do this would be:

```py
from typing import Any, NewType, Union, List, Iterable, Optional

Key = NewType('Key', Any)
Key._aka = set(['key', 'k'])

Val = NewType('Val', Union[int, float, List[Union[int, float]]])
Val.__doc__ = "A number or list of numbers."
```

But there's two reasons I don't like this:

- I have to copy paste the name of the new type I'm making three times (not D.R.Y. and prone to mistakes)
- I don't like to "externalize" the assignment of optional additional information (`_aka` and `__doc__`)

So I came up with this:

```py
from typing import Any, NewType, Union, List, Iterable, Optional

def new_type(name, tp, doc: Optional[str]=None, aka: Optional[Iterable]=None):
    """Make a new type with (optional) doc and (optional) aka, set of var names it often appears as"""
    new_tp = NewType(name, tp)
    if doc is not None: 
        setattr(new_tp, '__doc__', doc)
    if aka is not None: 
        setattr(new_tp, '_aka', set(aka))
    globals()[name] = new_tp  # is this dangerous? Does scope need to be considered more carefully?
```

which then gives me the interface I'd like:

```py
new_type('Key', Any, aka=['key', 'k'])
new_type('Val', Union[int, float, List[Union[int, float]]], doc="A number or list of numbers.")
```

But I'm not sure of that `globals()[name] = new_tp` thing. It seems it would be benign if I'm defining my types in the top level of a module, but not sure how this would fair in some edge case nested scopes situation.

Comment: is there any reason you can't simply `return` the new type and assign it to a variable instead of assigning to the global dict inside the function?

Comment: @Dan. Of course, I can, but that wouldn't be D.R.Y. If by chance I ever misspell one of the names (I will!), well... problems there will be down the line.

Comment: A situation I'd like even more is to be able to say `Key = new_type(Any)`, and that the `new_type` would take the name of the variable I'm assigning to (`Key`) to use as the name of the new type. Like what happens when I do `class Key(Any): ...`. But I have no clue how to do that, or if it would be considered dark magic.

Comment: One problem is that, although it would be odd, it would be possible to create one of these in a function scope and of course changing `globals()` would be wrong then. I think an indication of how hard this is is that even the built-in `namedtuple` function forces you to repeat yourself. It might be cleanest to put up with mentioning the name twice. If there is any non-hacky solution at all, I suspect it would involve using the class keyword and maybe metaclasses, but I don't know enough about those to know.

Comment: @ArthurTacca: Yes, your function scope example, is what I was thinking of when I said "nested scopes". And yes others (`namedtuple`  you mention, but also `type`, `collections.TypeVar` etc.) have this annoying constraint. No doubt there's a good reason -- but then it'll trace down to a limitation of the language itself. A PEP, anyone?

Comment: What's wrong with using class inheritence directly e.g. `class Key(Any): aka=['key', 'k']`  (you'll have to imagine the line break because you can't put those in comments)

Comment: To answer my own question: you need to call `typing.NewType()` so that it's a distinct type (and has the correct name). Inheriting from something else will compare equal to the old type.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way you create a new type is to just write a new class:

```
class Key:
    def __init__(self, key: object) -> None:
        self._key = key
        self._aka = set(['key', 'k'])

class SqlString(str):
    """A custom string which has been verified to be valid SQL."""
```

Note that this approach avoids the DRY and scoping concerns that you had.

You use NewType only for when you *don't* want to add any extra attributes or a docstring -- doing `Foo = NewType('Foo', X)` is basically like doing `class Foo(X): pass` except with slightly less runtime overhead.

(More precisely, type checkers will treat `Foo = NewType('Foo', X)` as if it were written like `class Foo(X): pass`, but at runtime what actually happens `Foo = lambda x: x` -- Foo is the identity function.)

---

We do run into a complication with your second Union example, however, since Unions are not subclassable (which makes that NewType illegal, as per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#newtype-helper-function)).

Instead, I would personally just do the following:

```
# A number or list of numbers
Val = Union[int, float, List[Union[int, float]]]
```

IMO since types are supposed to be invisible at runtime, I think it makes sense to just not bother attaching runtime-available documentation.

Comment: Question @Michael0x2a. What's the relationship between `Key` and `SqlString`?.

Comment: @thorwhalen -- they are two different examples of how to create a custom classes/custom types. Key is a custom class/type that inherits only from object and defines a few custom fields. SqlString is a custom class/type that inherits from str and does nothing else.